# Can I have the same element repeat more than once in a list?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

thanks in advance.
So I'm a Unity developer and i have a list of available idle states for my AI character.
Currently I'm controlling the order of execution through my public list in my inspector witch works fine, however when I try to execute the same element the second time in my order of execution my list gets stuck between the repeating element and the next one in a loop and is not running through the rest of my elements.

Should I post my list script?
Thanks again guys.

```
public class Idle : MonoBehaviour
{
public enum IdleState
{
    BasicIdle,
    PlayingWithKids,
    Playfull,
    Curious,
    Bored,
    MoveToCamera,
    Waiting,
    PlantMode,
    Shy,
    Crying
}

public List<IdleState> availableIdleStates = new List<IdleState>()
{
    IdleState.BasicIdle,
    IdleState.PlayingWithKids,
    IdleState.Playfull,
    IdleState.Curious,
    IdleState.Bored,
    IdleState.Waiting,
    IdleState.PlantMode,
    IdleState.Shy,
    IdleState.Crying
};


private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Time.timeSinceLevelLoad > prevIdleStateChangeTime + currentStateDuration)
    {
        int i = availableIdleStates.FindIndex(x => x.Equals(currentIdleState))+1;
        //i %= availableIdleStates.Count;
        if (i >= availableIdleStates.Count)
        {
            i = 0;
            //TODO: Shuffle available states list 
        }
        changeState(availableIdleStates[i]);
    }
    switch (currentIdleState)
    {
        case IdleState.BasicIdle:
            if (Time.timeSinceLevelLoad > subStateChangeTime + subStateDuration)
            {
                subStateDuration = Random.Range(20f, 30f);
                Debug.Log(subStateDuration);
                int randInt = Random.Range(0, 1);
                subStateChangeTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
                switch (randInt)
                {
                    case 0:
                        CurrentMovingState = Moving.MovingState.MoveAndRotateToTarget;
                        return;
                    case 1:

                       CurrentMovingState = Moving.MovingState.MoveAndRotateToTarget;
                        return;
                    //case 2:

                    //   CurrentMovingState = Moving.MovingState.MoveAndRotateToTargetWithRotation;
                    //    return;
                }
            }
            return;
```

this methos is being called every state change

```
private void changeState(IdleState NewState)
{
    currentIdleState = NewState;
    prevIdleStateChangeTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
    subStateChangeTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
    subStateDuration = -1;
 }
```

Comment: Please share a copy of your code, thanks.

Comment: How do I actually do that with the comment box characters limitation? sorry for being a dumb newbie haha

Comment: Got it! Every available state has its own definition. So for example having basic idle to execute more than once in my list.

Comment: Just to clarify you want to assign specific code to be executed for each of the states of your idle states?

Comment: Yup. Every idle state has its own movement and behavior parameters. all i want to do is to be able to have the exact same idle state run multiple times in different indexes in my public inspector list and actually go to the rest of the elements without being stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: What causes the state to change is it time based, just so I can update my solution.

Comment: Its is time based. and the changing of states works fine by the index order in my inspector. the problem is when I try to add the same idle state multiple times in my inspector list.

Comment: Hi, i've edited my answer but you should use a class with a single enum value in it and create an array of that class instead of holding a list of enum values.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, side note: I'm really new to scripting, still learning

Answer (score 0):

```
private enum states
{
    state1,
    state2
}

private states current;


private void stateChanged()
{
    switch (current)
    {
        case states.state1:

            break;

        case states.state2:

            break;

        default:

            break;
    }
}
```

The code example above shows how you can use enums with switch case statements to execute specific code depending upon the current state so you would first set the current state `current = states.state1;` and then call the stateChanged method which will execute the right code .

You also don't need a list for all of the states if you just want the program to cycle through them in the order they are set up e.g going from state1 to state2 you can simple do that by setting current         `current = (states)(int)current + 1;` after a certain time limit has been reached.

Comment: Yeah I believe the list is needed because I'm also changing the list of available list in runtime, thanks a lot man. also I edited my post take a look

Comment: So do want a random state to be picked or do want to add and remove elements in the list at runtime?

Comment: also as you can see in my script I'm using a return and not a break, is this the right way to go?

Comment: You should use break to break out of the case switch statement as return is used for giving back values to the caller.

Comment: I have another switch statement for every character "mood". each case holds the list of available states that can be used in current mood. this is also working fine, except when I try to repeat the same state more than once.

Comment: Shouldn't it return to the caller though? so it can check the current state and act accordingly?

Comment: No when the switch case statement gets called it will check whatever the value of your currentIdleState variable is and then execute the correct code accordingly, I'm not sure but I think the way you have your code setup might be causing the issues. Just some advice when trying to implement some new code you should try to make the most basic implementation possible as it's easier to debug and you can just add more to it later. For example having just two states to start of with which would make debugging and testing the code easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and generosity man, any idea for my repeating elements? I'm completely lost.. thought about using Unity's GUI maybe? even if you could like refer me to a specific google search since Ive read every post possible to every wording I could possibly think of.

Comment: could it be that whats causing the problem is the math in the start of my fixed update?

Comment: Honestly i'm not sure what could be causing the best thing i could suggest would be to write again from the scratch and test each part of it as you make it again. Sorry i couldn't help anymore. Heres a youtube video about the state pattern that you might find useful. https://youtu.be/Vt8aZDPzRjI

Comment: could it be an Enum problem? Because the states are in an Enum they have an int value witch makes this list just go back to the called state and start again from there?

Comment: Would you be able to post a MCVE it will let me run and test the code on my side and see if I can find the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example